# No exception trace on Laravel

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I begin on Laravel. I've got an error (I think its related to the ORM or the routes), but there is no info about it.
I just got a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." without more info.

My display_errors is enabled on my php.ini.
Do you have an idea of where it comes from ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable debug in `app/config/app.php`.

But you also have access to the full log by executing:

```
 php artisan tail
```

Check the log folder `app/storage/logs` if this command doesn't work for you.

Comment: Wow, what a quick answer ! Enabling debug in app.php did the job ! I thought doing it in app/config/local/app.php was enough, but no... I will check the php artisan command ;) Thanks !

Comment: Actually `app/config/local/app.php` was the right place for it, since you don't want debugging enabled in production. You need to setup your local environment, see the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) for more on that.